# In a basic GUI, I can only see the frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is the information for what I think is a correct basic GUI, but only the frame is showing up. I don't know why this is. I have everything initialized and set to visible and added, but it acts like nothing is added. Thanks for the help!

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class basicButtonPress 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        frame = new JFrame("Test Pop - Up");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        button = new JButton("Test");
        label = new JLabel("This is test label");
    }
}
```

Comment: Always stick to java naming conventions. Make sure your class names starts in Uppercase alphabet. Just wanted to give a suggestion. Glad that you figured out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `new JFrame()` twice; same with `JPanel`, `JButton` and `JLabel`.  Remove the duplicates and you'll be closer to fixing the problem.